# Adding a getter makes using an underscore incorrect syntax

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, getter-setter, synthesize

I have a class with the following header:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *foo;

@end
```

With the following implementation that does not show any errors:

```
#import "CustomClass.h"

@implementation CustomClass

- (void) setFoo:(NSString *)foo {
    _foo = foo;
}

@end
```

Being a complete beginner to Objective-C, I am baffled when I add the following method to the implementation:

```
- (NSString *)foo {
    return _foo;
}
```

because now there is an error in the method `use of undeclared identifier 'title'` and it recommends that I change `_foo` to `foo`. Not only does it say that in the newly added method, it also says it in the previous setter method. I have tried to look up the situation and I have not found a satisfactory response. Related questions talk about `@synthesize`, but I have [read that it is not necessary](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html), so I am not sure what the problem is.

Thanks in advance!

-GoldDove

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A property is not automatically synthesized 
if you implement *both* setter and getter method for that property, so you have to
synthesize it explicitly:

```
@synthesize foo = _foo;
```

(or add the instance variable `_foo` explicitly.)

The same applies if you implement the getter method for a read-only property.

(If you implement all necessary accessor methods for a property then the compiler
does not assume anymore that this property is necessarily backed up by an instance
variable.)

Comment: Ohhh, that makes so much more sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This is because obj c creates the ivar for you along with a setter and getter whereas you used to have to synthesize the ivar yourself. If you manually create the setter AND getter, however, it assumes that you do not want the ivar and so you then have to synthesize it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two different names for your class.  CustomClass and BlogPost. I suggest you make them both one or the other.

Comment: Sorry, I was changing my real class to an arbitrary example but I seemed to have missed that. It is now fixed. Thanks!